# ZSH: Is it possible to get file completion to display results in a case-sensitive order?

Tags: linux, zsh

Here's an example of what I mean:

In my home dir, I have three directories starting with "work":

```
$ ls | grep ork
WorkProjects
workspace
workspacepython
```

Notice that "WorkProjects" starts with a capital W.

Now, I want to cd into one of them. I typically type "cd work" followed by TAB. Resulting in:

```
$ cd work
WorkProjects/     workspace/        workspacepython/
```

Where the first entry is the folder starting with the capital W. I want it to sort it according to best match first, e.g. folders actually starting with "work" case-sensitive first, and then any case-insensitive matches.

Wanted result:

```
$ cd work
workspace/        workspacepython/     WorkProjects/
```

Is this possible to change somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm *afraid* the answer to your question is:

- yes it is possible,
- btw that is the default behavior
- so you'll have to check your shell configuration.

try using this:

```
% zsh -f # starts new shell ignoring all your configuration options
% autoload compinit && compinit # starts the completion system
% cd /tmp && mkdir test && cd test && mkdir work Work wooork
% cd w[TAB]
wooork/ work/    Work/
```

You'll notice it will list `work` before it lists `Work`.

PS: did you notice your shell prompt character is `$`? Are you using zsh or bash?

Comment: Yes, you're quite right. It is the default behavior. This actually stems from "oh-my-zsh" which I've been using as well. And in there there is a simple option of case-sensitivity which I had missed.

Thanks!